# how to change lines at the same time - VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change same lines at the same time. 
for example I want to change `{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }` at anywhere on my file.js. (I don't want to use `Replace`)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select `{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }` with your mouse and press `cmd + shift + L` (or `ctrl + shift + L`) to select all occurrences of it in your file. Then, you can change them all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. Ctrl + F  (backgroundColor: '#ufff')
2. Alt + Enter

This will select every instance and give each an active cursor.  Hit Esc to exit multi cursor mode.